# Java Android Studio libGDX Api 16 Crash

Tags: java, android, api, libgdx

My app crashes if I use a phone with API 16, but it is perfectly fine with api 22. Here is the error code for API 16:

```
09-15 20:31:26.806  17349-17349/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: src.bestScore
        at src.MainClass.<init>(MainClass.java:119)
        at src.AndroidLauncher.onCreate(AndroidLauncher.java:28)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5185)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2071)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2132)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: First thing you should do is check your minimum sdk in either your AndroidManifest or build.gradle. Another thing you can try is turn off instant run, then clean/make/rebuild your project again.

Comment: You are probably using some Java 7 API that didn't exist in API16,

Comment: Are you using try-with-resources anywhere in your code? As far as I know, that's the only Java 7 feature that will cause problems on older APIs. But Lint should tell you that when you're compiling (i.e. show warning or error if your code has try-with-resources but your minSdkVersion is < 19).